# Toggle an info box with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is my first personal project on AngularJS, so there might be something obvious on the code and I cannot see it.

I have two divs which each of them have an icon. First one have an info icon and the second one an exit icon.

```
<div class="info" ng-show="myCtrl.showInfo">
   <i class="fa fa-close" ng-click="myCtrl.toggleInfo()"></i>
   <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>

<div class="settings" ng-show="myCtrl.showInfo">
   <i class="fa fa-close" ng-click="myCtrl.toggleInfo()"></i>
   <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>
```

I can either click on the exit or info icon to show and hide the first div. Here is the related part of my controller:

```
myCtrl.showInfo = true;

myCtrl.toggleInfo = function () {
     myCtrl.showInfo ^= myCtrl.showInfo;
}
```

It works on the first click, but after that the value `myCtrl.showInfo` turned to `0` from `false` and it stops working.

Version: Angular 1.5.8

Comment: Show the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no logic is tied to this action, other than a show/hide, then you could do it without a function in your controller.

```
<div class="settings" ng-show="myCtrl.showInfo">
   <i class="fa fa-close" ng-click="myCtrl.showInfo = !myCtrl.showInfo"></i>
   <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems this works and it is the cleaner way. Thank you. Will accept the answer after the time limit of SO

Comment: @Tasos having code inside controller would make it more testable, instead of having it on template? Also unnecessarily it will clutter up your template

Answer (score 0):

You had a wrong toggling expression, do correct it to below using `!`.

```
myCtrl.toggleInfo = function () {
     myCtrl.showInfo = !myCtrl.showInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` and change controller function :

```
<div class="info" ng-if="myCtrl.showInfo">
   <i class="fa fa-close" ng-click="myCtrl.toggleInfo()"></i>
   <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>

<div class="settings" ng-if="!myCtrl.showInfo">
   <i class="fa fa-close" ng-click="myCtrl.toggleInfo()"></i>
   <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>
```

//Controller

```
myCtrl.showInfo = true;

myCtrl.toggleInfo = function () {
     myCtrl.showInfo != myCtrl.showInfo;
}
```